# Why does ffmpeg show a corrupted video when receiving stream in MPEG TS format?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, wireshark, h.264, transport-stream

I'm trying to stream a CCTV footage using RTP/MPEGTS. I can properly view it in vlc using the following command(I'm using windows 10):

```
vlc --demux ts rtp://239.194.115.71:5000
```

[image: vlc]

The problem arises when I tried to receive and play it in ffmpeg using the following command:

```
ffplay -f mpegts rtp://239.194.115.71:5000
```

I'm getting a semi decent video for the first 5 seconds:

[image: first5]

After 5 seconds the video gets droopy and corrupted
(note that the top part of the video seems to be unaffected)

[image: after5]

Compete logs can be found here: https://pastebin.com/7CvbFsQK

This is some of the logs from ffmpeg:

```
[udp @ 00000296e31a4480] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)
[udp @ 00000296e319f400] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] Unable to seek back to the start
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] Unable to seek back to the startf=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[h264 @ 00000296e31c9e80] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 00000296e31c9e80] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00000296e31c9e80] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 00000296e31c9e80] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00000296e31c9e80] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000296e31c9e80] no frame!
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[h264 @ 00000296e31c9e80] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 00000296e31c9e80] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00000296e31c9e80] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 00000296e31c9e80] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00000296e31c9e80] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000296e31c9e80] no frame!
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[h264 @ 00000296e31c9e80] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 00000296e31c9e80] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00000296e31c9e80] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 00000296e31c9e80] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00000296e31c9e80] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000296e31c9e80] no frame!
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[h264 @ 00000296e31c9e80] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 00000296e31c9e80] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00000296e31c9e80] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 00000296e31c9e80] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00000296e31c9e80] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000296e31c9e80] no frame!
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[h264 @ 00000296e31c9e80] left block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1
[h264 @ 00000296e31c9e80] error while decoding MB 0 6, bytestream 150225
[h264 @ 00000296e31c9e80] concealing 7489 DC, 7489 AC, 7489 MV errors in I frame
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[h264 @ 00000296e31c9e80] concealing 7487 DC, 7487 AC, 7487 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[h264 @ 00000296e31c9e80] cabac decode of qscale diff failed at 64 24
[h264 @ 00000296e31c9e80] error while decoding MB 64 24, bytestream 15698
[h264 @ 00000296e31c9e80] concealing 5265 DC, 5265 AC, 5265 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192  0B f=0/0
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000296e31a4880] changing packet size to 204
Input #0, mpegts, from 'rtp://239.194.115.71:5000':q=    0B f=0/0
  Duration: N/A, start: 67510.427322, bitrate: N/A
  Program 1
    Stream #0:0[0x1011]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
[h264 @ 00000296e8195180] left block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1
[h264 @ 00000296e8195180] error while decoding MB 0 6, bytestream 150225
[h264 @ 00000296e8195180] concealing 7489 DC, 7489 AC, 7489 MV errors in I frame
[h264 @ 00000296e3235200] concealing 7487 DC, 7487 AC, 7487 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 00000296e3235200] cabac decode of qscale diff failed at 64 24
[h264 @ 00000296e3235200] error while decoding MB 64 24, bytestream 15698
[h264 @ 00000296e3235200] concealing 5265 DC, 5265 AC, 5265 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 00000296e819b400] concealing 7425 DC, 7425 AC, 7425 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 00000296e8195180] cabac decode of qscale diff failed at 27 49
[h264 @ 00000296e8195180] error while decoding MB 27 49, bytestream 5976
[h264 @ 00000296e8195180] concealing 2302 DC, 2302 AC, 2302 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 00000296e8195180] concealing 4980 DC, 4980 AC, 4980 MV errors in I frame
[h264 @ 00000296e819b400] concealing 1322 DC, 1322 AC, 1322 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 00000296e3235200] concealing 619 DC, 619 AC, 619 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 00000296e82ce6c0] concealing 6875 DC, 6875 AC, 6875 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 00000296e819b400] concealing 6462 DC, 6462 AC, 6462 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 00000296e819bb80] concealing 4570 DC, 4570 AC, 4570 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 00000296e8195180] concealing 4196 DC, 4196 AC, 4196 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 00000296e819bb80] cabac decode of qscale diff failed at 1 15
[h264 @ 00000296e819bb80] error while decoding MB 1 15, bytestream 20111
[h264 @ 00000296e819bb80] concealing 6408 DC, 6408 AC, 6408 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 00000296e8195180] left block unavailable for requested intra mode
[h264 @ 00000296e8195180] error while decoding MB 0 46, bytestream 59771
[h264 @ 00000296e8195180] concealing 2689 DC, 2689 AC, 2689 MV errors in I frame
[h264 @ 00000296e819bb80] concealing 3478 DC, 3478 AC, 3478 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 00000296e819bb80] concealing 6970 DC, 6970 AC, 6970 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 00000296e8195180] concealing 6875 DC, 6875 AC, 6875 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 00000296e8195180] left block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1
[h264 @ 00000296e8195180] error while decoding MB 0 31, bytestream 92665
[h264 @ 00000296e8195180] concealing 4489 DC, 4489 AC, 4489 MV errors in I frame
[h264 @ 00000296e3235200] concealing 2421 DC, 2421 AC, 2421 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 00000296e819b400] concealing 7268 DC, 7268 AC, 7268 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 00000296e3235200] concealing 6889 DC, 6889 AC, 6889 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 00000296e82ce6c0] concealing 4213 DC, 4213 AC, 4213 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 00000296e819bb80] concealing 6255 DC, 6255 AC, 6255 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 00000296e8195180] left block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1
[h264 @ 00000296e8195180] error while decoding MB 0 2, bytestream 169691
[h264 @ 00000296e8195180] concealing 7969 DC, 7969 AC, 7969 MV errors in I frame
[h264 @ 00000296e3235200] concealing 1707 DC, 1707 AC, 1707 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 00000296e82ce6c0] left block unavailable for requested intra mode
[h264 @ 00000296e82ce6c0] error while decoding MB 0 20, bytestream 16584
[h264 @ 00000296e82ce6c0] concealing 5809 DC, 5809 AC, 5809 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 00000296e3235200] cabac decode of qscale diff failed at 17 15
[h264 @ 00000296e3235200] error while decoding MB 17 15, bytestream 18775
[h264 @ 00000296e3235200] concealing 6392 DC, 6392 AC, 6392 MV errors in P frame
```

Wireshark packet dump:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zppjXVgEcL8Ws-xP3e1J7NJF1UGdPzMA

What could be problem with ffmpeg playing the stream, could it be the codec used?

Comment: Share full logs. `circular_buffer_size` is reported as being unavailable. That option requires pthread support but your build does not have it. So packets may be getting dropped, leading to decoding errors.

Comment: compete logs can be found here: https://pastebin.com/7CvbFsQK, 
I also added a link in post's body.

Comment: Which ffmpeg version do you use? I think this is a bug which occur when play fragmented MP4(MPEGTS).

Comment: ffmpeg version N-93322-gd227ed5d59